# How do I call activity indicator at process time

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

After clicking the button, the next page is taking a little time to load. This is because the next page creates many dynamic label controls to show data. How do I show activity indicator at process time.

```
private async void ProductTypeButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
    await Navigation.PushAsync(new ProductPage(_ViewModel));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before PushAsync to the `ProductPage`, you need make the `ActivityIndicator`  run and after successfully navigating to `ProductPage`, you can set `IsLoading = false`. Here's the code snippet below for your reference:

**Code-behind:**

```
  private bool _isLoading; 

        public bool IsLoading
        {
            get => _isLoading;
            set
            {
                _isLoading = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("IsLoading");
            }
        }
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BindingContext = this;
        }

        private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            IsLoading = true;
             
            //set the delay time to push smoothly 
            await Task.Delay(300);

            try
            {
                await Navigation.PushAsync(new ProductPage());
            }
            finally
            {
                IsLoading = false;
            }

        }
```

**Xaml:**

```
<ActivityIndicator IsRunning="{Binding IsLoading}" ></ActivityIndicator>
```

Comment: Explain the delay. "push smoothly" - I don't know what that means. Raj already has something that takes significant time, why add another 300 ms?

Comment: This is because the next page is taking a little time to load which will need the delay time.

Comment: await statements happen one at a time. The page will not begin loading until after that delay is done, so it is wasted time. If you doubt that, make the delay longer, and it will be more obvious that  it makes the total time longer. Comment out the delay.

Comment: If I commented to `await Task.Delay(300);`, the ActivityIndicator started after 3 seconds, displayed for 2 seconds, and then the page coming.  If I using `Delay(300)` It taking the same amount of time, but the ActivityIndicator appears without delay after the click. @ToolmakerSteve

Comment: And I wanted this: the activity indicator is visible until the page loads.

Comment: Ah, Now I understand why - Without a delay, UI does not get a chance to update what is displayed. It had not occurred to me that PushASync would not allow current view to update; it immediately starts preparing the new page. Makes sense to me now.